# How can I define DPI Awareness of a fixed size WPF app?

Tags: wpf, windows, user-interface, dpi

I have a WPF application with **fixed Height and Width**. But from dpi scaling 150% onwards, the window get so magnified that it starts to get cutoff after 200%. I feel when scaling is increased the window size should not be increasing so much but the content inside should be magnified. Currently the dpi awareness of the app is set to per monitor.

How can I proportionally size the window and its contents according to the dpi scaling?

Answer (score 0):

Add manifest file in your WPF application, see e.g.:

https://github.com/qube7/qcomposite/blob/master/Qube7.Composite.Vsix/ProjectTemplates/Application/app.manifest

Comment: This is already there. Even after that application is behaving this way.

Comment: Which .NET version you use?

Comment: Min .NET 4.6.2 and Windows 10 Anniversary Update: https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/master/PerMonitorDPI/readme.md

Comment: Using .NET 4.6.2